# jquery fileupload error stack overflow

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am having problem in jquery fileupload, I have included jqueryfileupload, written js for fileupload, but when i now drag and drop the file on the selected area, it throw error in chrome something like this-

**Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.**
and in mozilla.
**my browser just hang up.**

Although my same code is running in my another project.
Thanks

Comment: please share some code, like what you have tried or infected portion of your code so others can propose a solution.

Comment: it is a normal code for jquery fileupload, but yes i got an another error of  WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true. In my console when I drop a file.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. I comment two lines into the onChange method.

```
_onChange: function (e) {
    var that = this,
        data = {
            fileInput: $(e.target),
            form: $(e.target.form)
        };
    this._getFileInputFiles(data.fileInput).always(function (files) {
        data.files = files;
        if (that.options.replaceFileInput) {
            that._replaceFileInput(data.fileInput);
        }
        /**
        *IF I put on comment this line, this solve my problem without meeting                
          bug. I don't measure the consequence.
        **/
        //if (that._trigger('change', e, data) !== false) {
            that._onAdd(e, data);
        //}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem, the problem was that my version of jQuery-ui was outdated. The reason this caused the error was that widgetEventPrefix got lost, something which has been fixed in later versions of jQuery-ui. In the _trigger method it takes the event type and prepends widgetEventPrefix. Since the widgetEventPrefix has been lost (it should be fileupload) the event type just stays as "change" instead of what it's supposed to be ("fileuploadchange"). This results in the function calling itself infinitely.

So to fix this just make sure you have the newest version of jQuery-ui.

Link to jQuery ui widgetEventPrefix bug: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8724